# AngularJs radion button click after checkbox not removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem. When I click on the radio button, the checkbox has check to be removed, but I could not do it.

```
<tr ng-show="selectBolum.id!=NULL" ng-repeat="burs in getHesaplama | orderBy:'-tam_oran/1' | filter:{id:selectBolum.id}">
        <td><b>{{burs.burs_adi + ' %' + burs.mat_oran*100 + ' '}}</b>{{burs.aciklama}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <input ng-show="burs.birlestirme=='HAYIR'" type="radio" id="radio" ng-click="newValue(burs.mat_oran)" ng-model="getRadiobtn" name="radiobtn">
          <input ng-show="burs.birlestirme=='EVET'" type="checkbox" ng-change="newDsc(burs.mat_oran,check)" ng-model="check" ng-checked="getRadiobtn">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

code

```
$scope.newValue =function(value) {
      $scope.getKalan = $scope.getUcret;
      $scope.getKalan = $scope.getUcret -(value*$scope.getUcret);
      $scope.check=false;
   }
   $scope.newDsc =function(value,check) {
     if (check == true) {
      if ($scope.getKalan == 0) {
       $scope.getKalan = $scope.getUcret;
     }
     else{
      $scope.getKalan = $scope.getKalan - (value*$scope.getUcret);
     }
     }
     else{
      $scope.getKalan = $scope.getKalan + (parseFloat(value)*$scope.getUcret);
     } 
   }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs?file=app.js can your create sample code here with stackblitz ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-b4vlg5?file=index.html

here

Comment: what you exactly want ? whenever you click on radio button any of two then if there any checkbox is click you have to uncheck that ?

Comment: When I click on any of the radio button, all checkboxes in the table will be approved.

Comment: by the way i am using google translate sorry for bad translation

Comment: Added answer @furkan-ergin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below changes :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-jmgsy5?file=index.html

```
$scope.checkBoxStatus = [];
        $scope.newValue =function(value) {
          $scope.getKalan = $scope.getUcret;
          $scope.getKalan = $scope.getUcret -(value*$scope.getUcret);
          $scope.check=false;
          $scope.checkBoxStatus = [];
          //$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).prop( "checked", false );
       }
```

```
 $scope.getReset = function () {
        $scope.getKalan = $scope.getUcret;
        $scope.checkBoxStatus = [];
       }
```

```html
 <input ng-show="burs.birlestirme=='EVET'" type="checkbox" ng-change="newDsc(burs.mat_oran,checkBoxStatus[$index])" ng-model="checkBoxStatus[$index]" ng-checked="checkBoxStatus[$index]">
```

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/LVfvsP

my problem is that it doesn't take action on the picture

Comment: didt not get ? you want to checked all checkbox if any of radio button click. right ?

Comment: all checkboxes unchecking.

Comment: all checkbox uncheck whenever radio button click ?

Comment: but if its not checked before click radio button ? you can make it `false` then in `newValue()` function

Comment: I tried but for some reason it didn't work when I do chrome debug it sees the value as undefined

Comment: Added link which working after changes. @FurkanErgin